# Add a blank line in Swift Playgrounds markup

Tags: swift-playground

I have written some markup text accompanying my Swift Playground.
How can I add vertical space to separate paragraphs from each other?

Blank lines in the editor are ignored while parsing and do not result in a blank line, as soon as the markup is rendered.

```
/*:
Paragraph 1 goes here


Paragraph 2 is not seperated through a blank line.
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A documentation of features in swift playgrounds markup can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/MarkupFunctionality.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497-CH54-SW1).

1. Use the escaping character `\` proceeded by a blank line in the editor.
2. Use the non-breaking character `&nbsp;` surrounded by blank lines in the editor.

As a result:

```
/*:
Paragraph 1 goes here


Paragraph 2 is not seperated through a blank line.

\
Paragraph 3 is seperated through a blank line.

&nbsp;

Paragraph 4 is separated through a somewhat larger vertical space.

\
\
Paragraph 5 is separated through two blank lines.
*/
```